# jQuery if true than do inside line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small function. Dirty..

```
if(defaults["debug"] == true){ $('#get_debug').append(url + "<br />"); }
```

is it possible to write something like follow.

```
$('#get_debug').ifdebug.append(url + "<br />");
```

Thanks

Comment: for ur purpose u have modify ur jquery file..

Comment: you can write a custom plugin method which will return the elements if the condition is met

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uev62/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't see why you would, but sure it's possible

```
$.fn.ifdebug = function() {
    return defaults["debug"] == true ? this : $();
}
```

then you could do

```
$('#get_debug').ifdebug().append(url + "<br />"); }
```

Comment: Cheers! This is perfect.